# TRS to USB microphone wiring

Tags: usb, microphone, trs

I am trying to use a microphone pulled out from an old video recorder. I can use a TRS connector and plug it into the AV - mic in jack. I am curious if there is a way to use USB - A interface.
In short is possible to map Out and GND to USB-A VCC,D-,D+,GND?

Will windows detect the device as Mic in if the wiring is correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, USB is a digital interface that talks data.

If you want to connect a microphone via USB to a computer, you need an USB sound chip that presents a sound device to PC and converts analog signals to digital audio data.

Comment: (And these can commonly be found for less than $10)

Comment: Thank you. I understand it now.